# Containing an output of Awk into a variable and comparing it against an integer

Tags: bash, awk, comparison

I've spent the last 90 minutes Googling this problem so I hope I am not asking a question that has been asked several times before.8

I am currently trying to parse a log file and need a specific value from a line. 
Text file contents:

```
read: 4163419415       0      0     4163419415   0   4395.007      0
read: 4163419415       0      0     4163419415   0   4395.007      0
read: 4163419415       0      0     4163419415   0   4395.007      1
read: 4163419415       0      0     4163419415   0   4395.007      0
```

I need to grab that last value (which can be variable) and do some checking against it.

```
COUNTER=1
while [ $COUNTER -lt 26 ]; do
    ECREAD=$(awk '/read:/{i++}i=='$COUNTER'{print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)
    echo $ECREAD
    if [ "$ECREAD" > 0 ] 
        then
            echo "fail"
    fi
let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

My problem is the if statement is always true regardless of what value $ECREAD is. 
I have tried

```
[[ $ECREAD =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]] && echo integer
```

to verify that the variable is an integer.

I have also tried removing any white space that may be at the end of the variable by piping the awk portion of the command into `sed 's/ *$//'` AND `sed 's/^ *//'` AND `tr -d ' '`

I have tried changing the [] around the IF statement into `[[]]` AND `(( ))`

I have tried changing the `>` symbol into the `-gt` symbol.

Comment: *NOT FINISHED* HIT ENTER ON ACCIDENT SORRY. @John1024  Thank you for your help, but I am still having issues, also I apologize for such a sloppy question. You were correct in your assumptions I mistyped the "example test" portion. it should be:
  read: 2553734844 0 0 2553734844 0 4386.350 0 so a float will not be required.

Comment: @John1024 Comment continued got hit by the 5 minute only rule while editing, trying to get use to these forums. When I used your code snippet it works perfectly, but when I add back in my counter I encounter the error  
    : integer expression expected  
I will have more than one "read:"(~24) row so I believe I need the counter. So I believe the issue is how I am implementing the counter.  
All corrections made by another user are correct.

Comment: I have added more information to the OP. I think I tried to be too vague and basic and kind of missed some important details and I apologize.

Comment: Please see my revised answer and tell if it has captured all the details.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer for Revised Question

Suppose that we have `inputfile`.  We want to examine only the first 24 lines.  If any of those lines start with `read:` and have a last column that is greater than zero, then we want to print `Fail`.

If that is the case, then:

```
$ awk '/^read:/ && $NF > 0 {print "Fail";} NR>=24{exit;}' inputfile
Fail
```

**How it works**

- `/^read:/ && $NF > 0 {print "Fail";}`

  For any row that starts with `read:` and whose last column, `$NF`, is greater than zero, then `Fail` is printed.
- `NR>=24{exit;}`

  `awk` makes available a record (line) counter called `NR`.  After line number 24 has been processed, the program will exit without reading further.

#### Alternative using a `bash` loop

If the goal is to use awk one line at a time inside of a bash loop, then try:

```
for ((counter=1; counter<26; counter++))
do
    ecread=$(awk -v num=$counter '/read:/ && NR==num {print $8} NR==num{exit;}' ./txt.file)
    echo ecread=$ecread
    if [ "$ecread" ] && [ "$ecread" -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "fail"
    fi
done
```

**How it works**

- `for ((counter=1; counter<26; counter++)); do`

  This starts a bash loop over counter.
- `ecread=$(awk -v num=$counter '/read:/ && NR==num {print $8} NR==num{exit;}' ./txt.file)`

  This passes in the value of the bash variable `counter` into awk as the variable `num`.  If line number `num` contains `read:`, then the value of field 8 is printed.  After processing line number `num`, awk exits.
- `if [ "$ecread" ] && [ "$ecread" -gt 0 ]`

  This starts an `if`-`then` statement.  The `then` part is executed if (a) `ecread` has a non-empty value and (b) if that non-empty value is greater than zero.

### Answer for Original Question

Try:

```
ECREAD=$(awk '/read :/{print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)
echo ECREAD=$ECREAD
if [ 1 = "$(echo "$ECREAD > 0" | bc)" ]
then
    echo "fail"
fi
```

#### Notes

- `/read:/` does not match anything.  The input, *at least as displayed in the question*, has a space between `read` and `:`.  Thus, the test is changed to `/read :/`
- The purpose of the code `{i++}o==$COUNTER'` was not clear and it was removed.
- The value of `ECREAD` in the sample input is a float: 4395.007.  The shell only does integer arithmetic.  However, `bc` handles floats well.  So the test was converted to use `bc`.
- When doing comparisons with the shell test command, `[`, The symbols `>` and `<` compare string values lexicographically.  For numeric tests, one can use the mnemonically-named `-eq`,  `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, or `-ge`.

The output from the above code on the provided sample input is:

```
ECREAD=4395.007
fail
```

#### Alternative Interpretation

On the chance that there is a misplaced space in the sample input, consider this alternative.  Assume that the input looks like:

```
read: 4163419415 0 0 4163419415 0 4395.007 0
```

Now, the 8th field is not a float but a zero.  In this case, `bc` is not needed and the code can be simplified to:

```
ECREAD=$(awk '/read:/{print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)
echo ECREAD=$ECREAD
if [ "$ECREAD" -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "fail"
fi
```

The output from the above code is:

```
ECREAD=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment line is a bit of a mess:

```
ECREAD=$(awk '/read:/{i++}o==$COUNTER'{print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)
```

There are three single quotes and no backslashes, which makes for trouble.  You probably need:

```
ECREAD=$(awk '/read:/ {i++}  o==$COUNTER {print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)
```

That's syntactically valid.  It isn't clear that it does what you expect.  The variable `i` is incremented if the pattern matches (it doesn't match your sample data) but is otherwise unused.  The test `o == $COUNTER` compares the unset variable `o` with `$0` (because `COUNTER` is an unset variable, and hence evaluates to 0).  Since the conditions is not true, the printing is not executed.  This might do what you intended:

```
ECREAD=$(awk '/^read :/ { print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)
```

Your shell '`if`' statement is a big mess:

```
[ if "$ECREAD" > 0 ] 
then
echo "fail"
fi
```

It should be:

```
if [ "$ECREAD" -gt 0 ] 
then
    echo "fail"
fi
```

or:

```
if [[ "$ECREAD" -gt 0 ]] 
then
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: My best guess is that `COUNTER` is some `bash` variable & looking at the mismatched single quotes, OP perhaps meant it as : `$(awk '/read:/{i++}o=='$COUNTER'{print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)`

Comment: @anishsane: That could be, but since `o` is uninitialized (0 or an empty string), and is never set, it doesn't matter much unless `$COUNTER` was also 0 (an empty string wouldn't work).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I aplogize, but this is what the line should have looked like 
    `ECREAD=$(awk '/read:/{i++}i=='$COUNTER'{print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
$ ECREAD=$(awk '$1~/read/{print $7}' input )
$ if [ $ECREAD -gt 0 ]
> then 
> echo fail
> else
> echo pass
> fi
pass
```

Comment: `ECREAD=$(awk '/read:/{i++}i=='$COUNTER'{print $8; exit}' ./txt.file)` I require the counter because there are multiple iterations and I believe the counter is causing an issue for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here a pure bash solution can be just as easy as parsing the file with `awk`. `read` has the ability to read the `space`, `tab` or `newline` delimited text (default: internal field separator `$IFS`) without changing the delimiter. You can then just read the first seven values into a junk variable and discard, leaving only the `ecread` value you are interested in.

The `awk` solution is fine as well, but if you are working in bash, it can fill your need as well without relying on an external process:

```
#!/bin/bash

## accept filename as first argument to script (default dat/ecread.dat)
fn="${1:-dat/ecread.dat}"

## validate file is readable
[ -r "$fn" ] || {
    printf "error: file not readable '%s'. Usage: %s <filename> (dat/ecread.dat)\n\n" "$fn" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

declare -i counter=1        # declare counter as int, set to 1

## read each line in data-file and discard first 7 values (while counter < 26)
while [ "$counter" -lt 26 ] && read a a a a a a a ecread || [ -n "$ecread" ]; do

    printf " ecread: %s" "$ecread"

    ## test ecread > 0, if so fail, if not OK
    [ "$ecread" -gt 0 ] && printf " -- fail\n" || printf " -- OK\n"

    counter+=1

done <"$fn"

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$ bash ecread.sh
 ecread: 0 -- OK
 ecread: 0 -- OK
 ecread: 1 -- fail
 ecread: 0 -- OK
```